# photoshop CS6: Always a blur when copying from a selection

Tags: border, selection, photoshop, blur

This issue is causing a lot of problems for me.

When I create a selection and then copy/cut the image there is always a blur inside the borders of the selection, how can I avoid/resolve this?

White image with Selection
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9FRl.png

When pasting the blur border inside it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h73qt.png

Comment: It seems it only happens if I have feather selected for rectangular Marquee tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First... make sure you do not have a default `feather` applied to the selections:

[image]

From the looks of your images it appears as though you are using the `feather` option to attain your rounded effect. (either through the toolbar, or from the drop down menu) If this is the case that is where your problem lies.

The `Feather` option gradually decreases the opacity from 100% to 0%, based on the value you entered into the menu.

A better option would be to create a selection, then go to the `Select > Modify > Smooth...` dialog box. This allows you to smooth the corners and create a rounded rectangle, sans feather.

[image]
[image]
[image]